# Rendering Partial Loads onces per input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partials

I'm rendering a partial for a form which looks like the below:

```
 = render partial: "shared/address", locals: {f: property_address, prop_hint: 'some hint'}
```

And the partial is:

```
= f.input :address_1, label: "Street address", hint: prop_hint
= f.input :address_2, label: "Apt / Suite"
= f.input :city, input_html: {class: 'cf half-width-field'}
= f.input :state, input_html: {class: 'cf eighth-width-field'}
= f.input :zip_code, input_html: {class: 'cf three-eighth-width-field last'}
```

The issue is that when I pass 2 variables into the locals hash, it doesn't recognize the second one. I traced the issue to the fact that the partial is rendered 5 times, once per input, but I have no idea why.

Comment: I see only one key-value pair passed in your `locals` hash. Where is the second one?

Comment: I removed the second one as it wasn't working, but added back (OP) so you can see my example fully.

Comment: Let us discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: You said you've determined the issue relates to the fact that the partial is rendered 5 times, but what did you discover that led you to that conclusion?

Comment: For everyone else, I set a breakpoint using Pry ( pryrepl.org ) and it hits the breakpoint 5 times.

Comment: Looks like it should work to me? How are you calling the partial? Through a loop?